# flutter doctor issues even with java 8

Tags: java, android, flutter, sdk

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04LTS, Android Studio v3.0.1, installed latest Android SDK API 30 & 29, Android SDK Build tools, Platform tools & Command-line tools(latest),downgraded to java jdk1.8, installed Dart plugin on VSCode, installed Dart and Flutter plugin on Android Studio, installed flutter using snap on terminal.

But when I run `flutter doctor`, i get this

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Linux, locale en_IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

It says the plugin not installed even after I installed it and restarted android studio as well.

When i run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, i get all licenses and accept them by typing `Y` in the terminal and even after this when i run `flutter doctor` it still gives me same result.

There was an issue with Java 9 so downgraded JDK to 1.8 and yet issue isn't resolved.

Answer (score 0):

run the following commands

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8*`
$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Comment: When i run second cmd, i get `ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /my-user/libexec/java_home -v 1.8*

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
`

Comment: so find your java installation directory and rerun the first command with the correct path which usually be this `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: use this tutorial to install java
https://medium.com/@rohancbandara/install-openjdk-and-set-java-home-path-in-ubuntu-2ce2bc3a8fb2

Comment: yeah done, could execute both and yet `flutter doctor` outputs same

Comment: check if you configure android studio directory properly in `$ flutter config` command
and also the same for sdk